# Is Go's interface{} the same as void* in C?

Tags: c, types, go

Since a variable of type `interface{}` can have any value, does that mean it is essentially a general pointer like a void* in C?

Comment: Please read ["Go data structures: interfaces"](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

Comment: @kostix  Thanks for the link, but what does this say that the golang spec does not?

Comment: It explains the implementation, from which it clearly follows `interface{}` is not "a general pointer like `void *` in C".

Comment: @kostix I was more curious of the underlying functionality and how Go makes `interface{}` a general container for other types.

Comment: Maybe it is quite late, but I really like your question. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While C's `void *` pointers and Go's `interface{}` variables share the property that you can store arbitrary types, there is one big difference: Go interface variables also store the type of the value they hold.

So while a C programmer is expected to make sure that any casts from `void *` pointers to specific types are safe, the Go runtime can check that any type assertions are correct.

The type information found in interface variables also allows for sophisticated runtime introspection through the `reflect` package, which would be impossible with a plain `void *` pointer.

Comment: so `interface{}` is like a `struct` with a `void*` and additional type data

Comment: Yes.  The type info is also used to decide how to dispatch method calls on non-empty interface types.

Answer (score 6):

I am inclined to say "Not at all!". But I admit that it may server the same purpose of "holding whatever comes along".

1. An `interface {}` is not a pointer so you cannot dereference it.
2. You can cast a `void*` to anything but type asserting an `interface {}` might result in a runtime panic.
3. It is complicated (or impossible) to determine the actual type a `void*` points to but package reflect lets you do this for `interface {}`.

So no! `interface {}` is the empty interface and has nothing to do with a `void*` in C with the small exception that both might be used to handle anything where you do not care about the real nature of it.

Comment: You might want to say something about the fact that an `interface{}` can hold primitive types too, whereas a `void *` points to something (unless you are being really untidy but it isn't guaranteed all of C's primitive types can be losslessly cast to a `void *`)

Comment: I think it's one of those square/rectangle things. An `interface{}` is a `void*`, but a `void*` is not an `interface{}` (because an interface has more than just a pointer. Is that fair to say?

Comment: @Brenden: No, I do not see any reason why one should explain the empty interface like this.  All these "construct X in language Y is like Z ind language U" is not always helpful.

Comment: @Volker it is helpful to relate unknown concepts with familiar ones.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the interface type involved is empty—it has no methods—then the itable serves no purpose except to hold the pointer to the original type. In this case, the itable can be dropped and the value can point at the type directly.
REF:
https://research.swtch.com/interfaces