# Variadic Input Parameters mixed type in golang

Tags: go

Is there a way to pass Variadic Input Parameters mixed type in golang ?

```
somefunc(100, "Tom", some_dictionary, some_slice)
```

Comment: do you mean like `fmt.Printf()`? e.g. `func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `interface{}` empty interface. As example:

```
func somefunc(nums ...interface{}) {
    for _, j := range nums {
        fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", j, j)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gKDCJf31Fo4

Comment: is this akin to void * in C language?

Comment: @forvaidya I've found this interesting question about the argument https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066637/is-gos-interface-the-same-as-void-in-c

Comment: it may or may not be like void * ; as per post. but I an thinking in the way we use void *;

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate various data types into variadic function make the parameter as an interface,here is a sample code for your scenario:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    some_slice := []int{1, 2, 3}
    some_dictionary := map[string]string{
        "data1": "val1",
        "data2": "val2",
    }
    someFunc(100, "Tom", some_dictionary, some_slice)
}

func someFunc(nums ...interface{}) {
    for _, v := range nums {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int 100
string Tom
map[string]string map[first:a second:b]
[]string [one two]
```

Comment: Wow - very useful and crisp example !!